# Cheap sensor for measureing air dissolved in water?

Tags: sensor, measurement, water

I have been experimenting a bit with [hydroponics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydroponics) lately, and one of the important things when building a hydroponic system is to aerate the water/nutrient solution. This is usually performed with an ordinary air pump for aquariums by hobby hydroponic growers.

I know you can buy professional [dissolved oxygen sensors](https://www.atlas-scientific.com/product_pages/sensors/do-sensor.html), but these seem to be quite expensive.

**My question is can you make or buy some simple sensor that can measure the amount of dissolved air in water?**

The sensor does not have to precise in any way, or provide any absolute values. I just want to see some sensor value rise when I aerate the water, and fall slowly as the aeration dissipates (and is absorbed by the plants). This should be sufficient for regulating the aeration.

Note that I am not asking about dissolved oxygen just dissolved air in general. :)

Comment: I think that the $160 will sound relatively inexpensive by the time you make your own.

Answer (score 2):

Deep ends on % aeration you can get, but:

- Density will fall as aeration % rises. Easily measured with eg a float.

  A driven vibrating element would be affected by density - say a piezo buzzer element.
- You MAY be able to use the paramagnetic properties of Oxygen. This can be used to measure O2% in air. How swamped it is by water I know not.
- Sound transmission properties will alter. Whether usefully is TBD.

Density sounds the easiest.